Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'computed'
<script setup lang="ts">
import { IonItem, IonCheckbox, IonItemSliding, IonItemOptions, IonItemOption, IonIcon } from "@ionic/vue";
import { ref, computed } from "vue";
import dayjs from "dayjs";
import { Haptics, ImpactStyle } from '@capacitor/haptics';
import { calendarOutline, flameOutline, closeCircleOutline } from 'ionicons/icons';

Vue version "vue": "^3.4.35". Source: package.json file
tsconfig file:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "lib": ["ESNext", "DOM"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

package.json file:
{
  "name": "habit-rabit",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vue-tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test:e2e": "cypress run",
    "test:unit": "vitest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "6.1.1",
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/camera": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/filesystem": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/ios": "6.1.1",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/preferences": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/share": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "^6.0.0",
    "@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.2.2",
    "@ionic/vue": "^8.2.0",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^8.2.0",
    "capacitor-ios-autofill-save-password": "^3.0.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.10",
    "firebase": "^10.8.1",
    "ionicons": "^7.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.35",
    "vue-router": "^4.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@capacitor/cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/vue": "^1.0.31",
    "@vitejs/plugin-legacy": "^5.0.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.5",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^13.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.3.0",
    "cypress": "^13.5.0",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.27.0",
    "jsdom": "^24.1.0",
    "terser": "^5.4.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "vite": "^5.0.0",
    "vitest": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.26"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project"
}

When running Ionic build command I am experiencing this error below. Please also see comments under the post. Basically the build does not proceed due to this error. Last week my IDE was highlighting this same error but the build was successful anyway.
Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'computed'.ts-plugin(2305)
import computed


Please, provide a way to reproduce. This would happen if you used old Vue version (2.6 or older)

@EstusFlask my Vue version is "vue": "^3.4.35". Source: package.json file. What else can i provide? Reproducing is hard as it would mean cloning entire repo.

It's unknown at which point the error occurs. If it's in ide only but doesn't happen on build then the problem is specific to ide. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . No need to clone. The problem that is specific to project setup needs to be reproducible with "hello world" app that has your config. It can be a repo or online like stackblitz

@EstusFlask the error is highlighted during ionic build if that's what you mean.
[Ionic] Building...

npx npm run build && npx cap copy
habit-rabit@0.0.1 build
vue-tsc && vite build
src/components/ActivityListItem.vue(40,10): error TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'ref'.
src/components/ActivityListItem.vue(40,15): error TS2305: Module '"vue"' has no exported member 'computed'.
[error] npx npm run build && npx cap copy Failed
[error] Build Failed.


If it's caused by vue-tsc, this means there's something wrong with the deps or tsconfig

@EstusFlask thanks ! I've added tsconfig and package.json file above in the original post. Can you please have a look?

The error is caused by vue-tsc command that is responsible for typechecking in the project.
The problem is @types/vue dependency, it should be removed. It's intended for Vue 1.x and prevents the built-in types from vue package by being recognized by TypeScript.

mate this is insane, how did you figure this out? so that i can understand it in the future.

Modern libs don't need @types at all because they have builtin types. Since vue version is correct, @types/vue package would be the first to suspect because it's the only thing that could affect it under normal circumstances with this tsconfig, unless there are some odd things in src/ that aren't reproducible.  @types/vue could be also installed by some old vue-related package and not directly, but it was in the deps here.  I dropped the files to freshly initialized ionic project and the error appeared, so there was not much room for error, since it was in ts compiler, not other tools

Also @types commonly match lib version they are intended for. Even if you don't know if a lib needs it, "1.0.31" is a big red flag
